# Trying to pull multiple rows from Database using a foreign key in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to pull multiple images and display them from a database table `multi_image` which have foreign keys that link to a row in table `posts`

Each row in the `posts` table is linked to one user but a user can have many posts 1:M relationship

Each row in `post` can have multiple pictures (up to 4 images maximum) but a picture can only belong to one post 1:M again

**PostsController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Multi_image;
use App\Post;

use App\User;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;
use function Sodium\compare;

class PostsController extends Controller
{
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}

public function show(\App\Post $post)
{
    $postId = $post->id;
    $mImage = DB::table('multi_image')->where('post_id', $postId)->pluck('image');
    $postsIm = Post::whereIn('id', $mImage)->paginate(5);
    return view('posts.show', compact('post', 'mImage'));
}
```

**Post.php**

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Multi_image::class);
    }
}
```

**Multi_image.php**

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Multi_image extends Model
{
    protected $table = "multi_image";

    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post', 'post_id');
    }
}
```

**show.blade.php**

```
  @foreach($mImage as $image)
        <div class="details_image">
            <div class="details_image_thumbnails d-flex flex-row align-items-start justify-content-between">
                <div class="details_image_thumbnail" data-image=""><img src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/images/{{$image }}" alt=""></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
    <div class="col-5">
        <img src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/images/{{$mImage->first() }}" class="w-100">
    </div>
                            .
                            .
                            .
```

**posts**
[posts table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5XvJ.png)

**multi_image**
[multi_image table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4CLE.png)

**SOLUTION**

Question has been corrected with working code

Specific code that made it work: Review show() in PostsController.php

Answer (score 0):

It's undefined because you've not defined it anywhere. Try using `App\Multi_image::all() as $image` in your foreach.

Also, your Model Classes seem to have wrong names. You should have called them `MultiImage` etc. - singular form, and tables in DB in plural - `multi_images`.

Comment: I have manage to solve the issue using another approach and adjusting the code
Thank you for you suggestions which I will keep in mind for future instances and I will make those changes to my Model and DB